# Awesomely Gifted?

Tags: adverbs

> This **awesomely gifted** man stood.

I may not get how to make sense, of this. If an individual may seem, maybe, to have gifts, *awesomely* may seem like an adverb, here. How may *awesomely* inform upon *gifted*? It may not make sense. How may a man get gifted, *awesomely*?

Comment: @Catija - They may be equal in meaning, but not in usage. (I think _extremely_ sounds much more natural in this context, i.e.: _extremely gifted man_ vs _awesomely gifted man_).

Comment: @J.R. Sure, it certainly sounds better and would be a more common usage... but there's no way to know the source... this could be 200 years old, in which case, "awesomely" meaning "in a way that inspires awe" might make more sense. "The man, who is so gifted that it inspires awe [in the less gifted], stood.

Comment: @J.R.: I think the reason OP's exact collocation doesn't sound completely "natural" is because ***awesomely*** is more likely to be used as an intensifier by people with limited language skills. Who'd be more likely to talk about someone being *awesomely **clever*** or ***smart***, rather than ***gifted***.

Comment: @Fumble - I was only trying to clarify Catija's comment, which could easily be misunderstood by a learner to say the two were completely interchangeable.

Comment: As @FumbleFingers alluded to, gifted in this sentence means talented in some way, like being smart, clever, agile, handsome. When I first read this sentence I thought it sounded like part of a description of the love interest from a romance novel.

Comment: I guess, I thought, a, maybe, adverb, here, informs upon how something may get done. So, I thought, if one may seem gifted, and an adverb may inform upon how something may get done, if one may seem gifted, the adverb may inform upon how they may seem gifted. Awesomely may seem like the adverb informing on how one, maybe, may seem gifted, here. I guess, I thought, how may one seem gifted, awesomely? Does someone, or, maybe, something, with awe, gift you?

Answer (score 2):

"Gifted" here means having talents or abilities, not that someone gave him a present. It's the political correct way of saying that someone is better than others in some way: we say he's "gifted" rather than "he worked hard", because saying someone else is better at something because of hard work is considered rude to people who are lazy and don't accomplish as much. The idea is that nature gave him this gift for free, not that he did anything to earn it.

"Awesome" literally means "inspiring awe", that is, leading people to look at or think of something with wonder and amazement. You might say that a great mountain is awesome, or that the power of a hurricane is awesome, because it is big and grand. Or in this case, that this person's talents are awesome, that is, that his skills are so great that others look at them with amazement.

In short, it's saying that this person is very, very good at something.